# Rails 3.2 Deploy to Subdirectory Kind of Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, asset-pipeline, subdirectory

I am trying to deploy my Rails 3.2 app to a subdirectory, /support, on an Apache server. Consulting the various posts, the only solutions that seem to have helped involve setting up a [symbolic link](http://kb.site5.com/ruby-on-rails/how-to-deploy-a-rails-3-application-to-a-sub-directory/) on the server and changing css image references slightly (two dots '..' required before /assets in the css url references--I can't seem to find the post on that one now). I am getting success in deployment to production with Capistrano, but then strangely after awhile something changes, the /support reference breaks and the stylesheets don't load. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

oh no, please don't deploy rails as sub-uri in that way, you are making yourself in trouble.

So far as I see, ( according to this post: http://kb.site5.com/ruby-on-rails/how-to-deploy-a-rails-3-application-to-a-sub-directory/ ) you created soft links, modified your `routes.rb`, and changed RAILS.root in environment.rb, and also changed your assets files...  all of these make your rails app messed up.

I suggest you use 'passenger' as rails server and checkout this post: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_rack_to_sub_uri, it's quite easier and simplier

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! This fix seems to be entirely on the server side of things, which is contrary to most posts. You're suggesting no changes to the Rails app as the cleanest way to do it?

Comment: @TimK. Yes, I am suggesting you don't modify 1 line of code of your Rails app, but just configure the server settings. And I believe this approach is the usual/common way. As far as I see, deploy to sub-uri by changing the `routes.rb` file is very strange and like a newbie :)

Comment: Your suggestion helped a lot. I now have only modifications on the server side, but am still having a problem with assets. In my css file, I can either put '/support/assets...' and it works on the production server and not development, or '/assets' and it works on development and not production. Make sense?

Comment: use `asset_path` in your CSS/JS files. see the http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Comment: I am now using asset_path, but it stays at /assets... and doesn't recognize the subdirectory /support/assets... any ideas?

Comment: the 'asset files(images, css, js files)' should stay in 'app/assets' folder. you should sit tight and spend 2 hours to study the guide 'step by step', then you will be clear.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take some time and do this. BTW, I noticed you're a developer in Beijing. I lived in China for 3.5 years and have been to Beijing many times.

Comment: You are welcome ~  :)  yeah I am living in Beijing. welcome back to China and wish you a good time here~